# Finding a sub-neighbourhood of a neighbourhood such that it's open, connected and simply connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Say there exists a neighbourhood $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ of a point $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Does there always exist another neighbourhood $V\subseteq U$ of $z$ such that $V$ is open, connected and simply connected? I'm sorry if this question is a trivial matter but i have only limited experience with topology and really would like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, if the word "neighborhood" means that $U$ is open, then there is a small open disk (i.e. interior of a perfect circle) $V$ centered at your $z$ that is also completely contained in $U.$ In topology books, such a $V$ is an element of a "basis" for the topology.

Comment: I use wikipedias definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_%28mathematics%29, but i guess what you say still holds.

Comment: In that case:  "A set V in the plane is a neighbourhood of a point p if a small disk around p is contained in V."